# Mustache JS Template Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I'm working with mustache js for the first time, this is the challenge i'm facing

here is mustache js code

```
//jquery linking
<script src="../jquery-tut/node_modules/jquery.js"></script>

//mustache js lnkng from cdn
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mustache@4.2.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
```

```
var orderTemplate = "" +
    "<li>" +
    "<p><strong>Name:</strong> {{name}}</p>" + 
    "<p><strong>Drink:</strong> {{drink}}</p>"; +
    "<button data-id='{{id}}' class='remove'>X</button>" +
    "</li>";

    function addOrder(orders){
        let rendered = mustache.render(orderTemplate, orders);
        $orders.append(rendered);
    };
```

the template doe not provide the desired result as i want to add a button, it's not taking effect how do i go about it

i tried to use Mustache Framework for templates in my code, I'm learning get, post & delete method with jquery. Every code so far has been quite okay but my mustache js is givin issues i need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Any IDE (including jsfiddle) should point out that you have an extra `;` - `{{drink}}</p>"; +`  - may just be a copy to the question issue, but it means your `<button>` is not part of the template.

Comment: My first time using [tag:mustache] so there may be alternatives - a quick look at a "getting started" tutorial and there's some other issues:   you're missing the `loop array` construct and it should be `Mustache.render` (otherwise I get `mustache not defined`).  Here's a fiddle with these added and derived (guessed) source data:  https://jsfiddle.net/3vw1rqty/

Comment: Your own JavaScript code (starting from `var orderTemplate = ...` until the end) is not contained in `<script></script>` tags, so the browser will not execute it. Also, you are not showing us how `$orders` is created, nor how `addOrder` is  called. Also, did you look in the browser's dev console for any errors? Please share those. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.